# Page in aps.net is not loading at all

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, telerik, vb.net-2010

I have a website project developed using Telerik's rad controls and Twitter's bootstrap in VS2010 (framework 4). I must say it is a large project and this problem was not there a couple of days ago. Problem is that I have few asp.net web pages under a particular folder which when requested to open on **localhost**, browser is in the loading state forever but page is not getting loaded. Earlier these pages were getting loaded without any problem whatsoever. And when I publish them on the **IIS server**, they work without any issue means there is no problem with the code.

I tried to debug on the **Page_Load of code behind** but I realized that server is never reaching there and I wonder what is causing this issue. I would also say that I had not changed any settings on OS or VS. I tried to copy the same page to an another folder to see if it works there but no luck. So folder does not seems to be any issue.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me crazy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nailed it down, finally:) Infinite loop was messing up, **Exit While** did the trick.